# Is there a way to make Maven warn or error on bad file extensions?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea, groovy

IntelliJ defaults to locating a new Spock test in the java/ folder rather that the groovy/ folder, so we periodically wind up with groovy tests in our java directory, which are not run.

Is there an option in Maven, or in a plugin, to fail a build based upon the presence of a file with an unwanted extension?

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven Enforcer Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) allows the writing of [custom rules](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html), which can applied to the build lifecycle. The plugin can be configured to [fail on the first rule that does not pass](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html#failFast).